# Session variable dropped .net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session, cookies

I have a web application (.net VB code) that utilizes session variables to store the username (here login name) and the profile (admin/client), authentication is handeled by asp membership. The application then relies on these session variables on the load events. This application has been running fine for a couple of years. However, recently users complain about occasional error messages after logging in and attempting to load a new page that needs one of these variables. It happens most frequently Chrome, but also IE and Firefox.

Users that experience the error need to log out and clear the browsing history, after that it works again. The error is not easy to replicate - I was able to trigger it on my machine 'violently' using the 'back' button a couple of times that eventually tripped it - then I had to clear my browsing history to get the application to work again.

What might cause this to happen?

the session gets set on the load event of the 'login' page with 'Session("Type") = "Admin"' and subsequent pages check for the value of Session "Type"

I understand that I could use a cookie instead, but I chose not to for security reasons. Could this be prevented using a cookie instead? or do I need to use the membership.getuser method to get the username and then look up the values in the database? That does not seem efficient.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

FYI, the ASP.NET Session ID is stored in a cookie that travels back and forth with each request/response.  The actual session state values for a given session are not stored in cookies ... they are stored on the server only.  They could be stored in memory, or in a SQL database, depending on how you've configured ASP.NET Session State.

But Session State can get destroyed for a variety of reasons.  IIS might suddenly decide to restart your Application Pool, for example, in which case all your Session State would be gone.

Basically, you need to write your web app to always handle the possibility that Session State may be empty.  If it is empty, then you probably need to redirect the user to the login screen to enter his credentials again.

Clearing the browsing history should have no effect, so I can't explain why that would help get past the problem.